# python - ctypes, retrieve value of void pointer sent to shared c library

Tags: python, ctypes

Im calling a cpp function from dll with ctypes

the function definition is

```
int foo(strc *mystrc, int *varsize);
```

And the structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    int type;
    int count;
    void *value;
} strc;
```

So what I tried in python was to define:

```
class strc(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('type', ctypes.c_int),
                ('count', ctypes.c_int),
                ('value', ctypes.c_void_p)]
```

And to call the function as

```
varsize = ctypes.c_int()
mystrc = strc()
foo(ctypes.byref(mystrc), ctypes.byref(varsize))
```

I can perfectly call the function and retrieve all values except for the "value". It should be an array of variables indicated by the "type", have size "varsize" and be an array of "count" variables.

How can I retrieve what is indicated by the void pointer?

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T> void iterate_strc_value(const void* value, int size)
{
    const T* element = reinterpret_cast<const T*>(value);
    for(int offset = 0; offset != size; ++offset)
        *(element + offset) // at this point you have the element at the offset+1th position
}

switch(strc_var.type)
{
    case 0: iterate_strc_value<char>(strc_var.value, element_count); break;
    case 1: iterate_strc_value<int>(strc_var.value, element_count); break;
    case 2: iterate_strc_value<std::string>(strc_var.value, element_count); break;
    default: // invalid type -> maybe throw exception within python?!
}
```

The `value` pointer is the pointer that you also named `value`, while `size` specifies the amount of elements within the array. The size of the type is not needed, as the size of your types is known at compile time.

Basically the function just converts the `void*` to a pointer of your desired type and then uses pointer arithmetic to iterate over the array. This approach is general enough to just iterate over any `void*` which points to an array as long as you know it's size.
You could also add a third argument as a callback which performs the given action on each element to keep specialized code outside of the template function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't have access to the cpp code so I'm not sure I could use this. I'm loading the compiled library with ctypes and calling the function from there.

Comment: @Presbitero, are you looking for this?: `ctypes.cast(mystrc.value, ctypes.POINTER(<ACTUAL CTYPE TO CAST TO>))`. The result can then be accessed as an array. And `POINTER` is really written all uppercase.

Comment: (if I do `type(mystrc.value)` I get `NoneType` and `print mystrc.value` I get `None`.) 
If I do as you said, for example `a=ctypes.cast(mystrc.value,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))` then `a` gives `<clibname.LP_c_float object at 0x000000000B7342C8>` which I have no idea how to handle.

Comment: If I then do `mystrc.value.contents` I get the following error
`Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
ValueError: NULL pointer access`

Comment: You can access `a` with the subscript operator `a[index]`. But as Python tells you that you're trying to dereference a null pointer by calling `contents`, I'd assume that your void pointer is actually really a null pointer and doesn't point into any valid memory region. Has `count` the value `0`?

Comment: for my trial test, count has value 1.